# How to use Eigen::Matrix4d as message type in C++ Actor Framework?

Tags: c++, serialization, c++-actor-framework

I'd like to use the Eigen::Matrix4d class as a message in the CAF. But I can't seem to write a good Inspector for it.

The error is as follows:

```
usr/local/include/caf/write_inspector.hpp:133:7: error: static assertion failed: 
T is neither inspectable nor default-applicable
```

I've tried passing the content of the Matrix4d element per element and tried some more elaborate approaches with Boost ([boost_serialization_eigen.h](https://gist.github.com/artivis/288898ff877130e9a58ed04aeb9e59b5#file-boost_serialization_eigen-h)), but I just keep getting the same error.

```cpp
#include <iostream> 
#include <caf/all.hpp>
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <Eigen/Geometry>
using namespace caf;
using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;


CAF_BEGIN_TYPE_ID_BLOCK(custom_types, first_custom_type_id)
  CAF_ADD_TYPE_ID(custom_types, (Matrix4d))
CAF_END_TYPE_ID_BLOCK(custom_types)

#include <iostream>

template <class Inspector> 
typename Inspector::result_type inspect(Inspector& f, Matrix4d& m) {
  return f(m.data());
}


void caf_main(actor_system& system) {
    Eigen::Matrix4d Trans; // Your Transformation Matrix
    Trans.setIdentity();   // Set to Identity to make bottom row of Matrix 0,0,0,1
    Trans(0, 0) = 42;
    std::cout << Trans << endl;
    // Spawn the actor
}

// creates a main function for us that calls our caf_main
CAF_MAIN(id_block::custom_types)
```

I realize this may be  a broad question, but any pointers in the right direction are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

(assuming CAF 0.17)

The inspection DSL doesn't really seem to cover this particular case very well. Probably the best solution for CAF 0.17 at the moment would be specializing on `data_processor` and calling `consume_range`:

```
template <class Derived>
auto inspect(data_processor<Derived>& f, Matrix4d& x) {
  auto range = make_span(x.data(), x.size());
  return f.consume_range(range);
}
```

This won't work with CAF's automatic string conversion, but you can provide a `to_string` overload as needed.

Comment: Using 17.5 since the data_processor seems to have been removed after, I get the following error: 

`/usr/local/include/caf/data_processor.hpp:501:18: error: no matching function for call to ‘caf::deserializer::apply(Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>&)`

Perhaps an easier, albeit uglier, way would be to use a struct and convert where necessary?

Comment: Can you provide the full source code to that error? The `consume_range` approach works for me as of CAF 0.17.6: https://gist.github.com/Neverlord/294d66d95e159d1675af8fa047f56806